# How to link a checkbox and a button in a specific record in MS Access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, checkbox

I am about to link a checkbox and a button in the MS Access form. the button becomes disabled when the checkbox is unchecked and becomes enabled whenever it is checked.
I have written lines to run this command. but the results are not satisfying. because all the same buttons become enabled when I check a checkbox. and all buttons become disabled when I uncheck a checkbox. (I mean there is no link between the button and the checkbox in a specific record.)
My code is:

Private Sub reqChooesed_Click()

```
 If Me.reqChooesed = True Then
        Me.Command1.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.Command1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[Example 1][1]
[Example 2][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNk9M.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZ6m.png

Answer (score 0):

Use the AfterUpdate event:

```vb
Private Sub reqChooesed_AfterUpdate()

    Me!Command1.Enabled = Me!reqChooesed.Value

End Sub
```

But all records will behave the same. For individual operation, bind the checkbox to a new Boolean field in the table, and move the button to the header or the footer of the form.